# PHP - how to generate optimized jpg images for PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, pagespeed

I have several files, I want to make them optimized images for PageSpeed Insights. How to do this with PHP using gd or imagemagick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload an image process it with the function bellow. This process cleans meta information from images and stop Google for being annoying.

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($target_file);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: Why create a new GD resource and then immediately overwrite it? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @timclutton You are right. When I answered I copied two different functions from an old script. The first resource was intended to be an overlayer over the real image. I updated my answer. Thanks for tip.